# Django. Jquery. escaping string with quotes error

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, quotes

In a small forum, any user can save posts. Sometimes those posts include words surrounded by quotes ( " " ). This gives me an error when I try to handle those strings with javascript.

I wrote some jquery code that uses the django variable like this:

```
new_text = "{{text|safe}}";
$("#text_p").text(new_text);
```

if I mark it as "safe" then javascript gives me a syntax error:

```
the text "(error here)word between quotes" the user posted
```

This is logical because javascript understands the quotes like this:

```
new_text = "this is the text "word between quotes" the user posted"
```

So, if I don't mark it as "safe" and let django escape the text, it doesn't give me an error, but the text looks like this:

```
 the text &quot;word between quotes&quot the user posted
```

I don't know what to do, and I guess it may not be simple cause if I use single quotes to declare the javascript variable, I will have the same problem when the user posts a text with single quotes. If I use a regex to replace double quotes and not mark the text as "text|safe", then other tags will be escaped and the text will be full of "<br /&gt" etc.

I have an idea that may work but is ugly and probably not the best option:
including the text in a `<p class = "hidden">` tag and then calling it using jquery.

So, the question is, how do I solve this?, is there a better way? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**:
I created a [Runnable](http://runnable.com/U-V70djKNQxztWOj/problem-between-django-context-variables-with-quotes-and-javascript-for-python) to explain it better.

Comment: I don't understand quite right your problem...can you please made a sample fiddle to help you in a better way(jsfiddle)...cheers :)

Comment: Couldn't simulate the error, anyway my effort and some further explanation is aviable here: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alejoss/g9jc3ow8/)

Comment: @RobertRozas I did simulate the error in this [runnable](http://runnable.com/U-V70djKNQxztWOj/problem-between-django-context-variables-with-quotes-and-javascript-for-python).

Answer (score 25):

Use [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) filter.
Example:

```
{{ string|escapejs }}
```

Comment: this was really helpful to me!

Comment: Beware that this won't translate python boolean to string and therefore will raise an error in JS (undefined variable True)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a partial solution, hope it helps someone in the future. It is not an elegant solution, so, if anyone has a better option, it will be welcomed.

I included the text that has a "quoted" word inside a html hidden tag.

```
python-django:
text_with_quotes = 'this is a text and a word between "quotes"'

html:
<p id = "new_text" class = "hidden"> {{text_with_quotes|safe}}</p>

js:
new_text = $("#new_text").text();
$("#text_p").text(new_text);
```

it works. But there may be a better option using javascript and/or python.

Comment: Quite some time later, but for the sake of those who would be tempted to use this 'solution'. What if your user submits the next text: `Hi, I'm Bob. <script>alert("This website is vulnerable to XSS!");</script> Nice to meet you.`